# Python multithreading two clients to run indefinitely at the same time with one server

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, networking, serversocket

I'm attempting to figure out a multithreading problem with two clients running forever at the same time sending pings to the server while the server continuously echos back a message.

I looked into multithreading after I found out how one client/server can echo back and forth forever.

When I added a second client, it would receive the last output of the first client. The second client would then echo repeatedly with the server while the first client never receives a message, freezing it.

I was stuck on this for several days so assistance would be nice.

Anyway, this is the code I been using to test:

**ClientA.py**

```
import socket
import time

host = '127.0.0.1' 
port = 2004
BUFFER_SIZE = 2000 

tcpClientA = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
tcpClientA.connect((host, port))

while True:
    data = 'this is client A'
    tcpClientA.send(data)
    data2 = tcpClientA.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    print " Client A received data:", data2
```

**Clientb.py** is the same as client A, but with a b

**Server.py**

```
import socket
import time
import thread

from threading import Thread 
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn 


BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1' 
TCP_PORT = 2004
tcpServer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
tcpServer.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) 

threads = []

def client(ip,port):
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(2048)
        conn.send(data)
    conn.close()

print "Server waiting"
tcpServer.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
tcpServer.listen(4)
while True:
    conn,addr=tcpServer.accept()
    thread.start_new_thread(client,(conn,addr))
tcpServer.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original `client` function isn't using the connection passed in, but the global variable `conn` which is overwritten on each connection.  `ip` is the connection passed to `client`.

Since your server code imports SocketServer, use it and simplify the code.  This code will create a thread for each client connection.  `self.request` is the socket connection:

```
#!python2
import SocketServer

class Handler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        while True:
            data = self.request.recv(2048)
            if not data: break
            self.request.sendall(data)

server = SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer(('',2004),Handler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your client handler threads use the socket in the variable `conn` that is assigned in the main thread to receive data from and send data to. Basically, you are always only using the last connection that was created.
This often becomes visible in the second client's output, right after starting it:

```
Client B received data: this is client A
```

From this point onwards, both client handler threads serve client B only, because this part of your `client` function ...

```
    data = conn.recv(2048)
    conn.send(data)
```

... uses this `conn` (socket) from the main thread, which gets overwritten every time a new client connects to the server:

```
conn, addr = tcpServer.accept()
```

Client A waits for data from the server at this point:

```
data2 = tcpClientA.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
```

But since both client handler threads in your server only listen and write to the socket created when client B connected, the client A process no longer receives data and blocks indefinitely waiting for some.

You already pass the respective connection to your client handler threads ...

```
thread.start_new_thread(client, (conn, addr))
```

... you just need to use it:

```
def client(ip,port):
    while True:
        data = ip.recv(2048)  # receive from ip
        ip.send(data)         # send to ip
    conn.close()
```